# Rails Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I think its because of my less knowledge of Ajax.

Using Ajax I'm trying to make a continuous ajax call to my server.
I am making ademo app for learning.

I have following code:

In my job_status/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Loading data ......</h1>

<div id = "job-id-container">
    Aditya
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function tick() {
      var ajaxOpts = {
            type: "get",
            url: "/job_statuses",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "status=reload"

        };
    $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    setTimeout('tick()', 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    tick();
});
</script>
```

In my job_statuses_controller

```
class JobStatusesController < ApplicationController
    def index       
        @job = JobStatus.last       
    end
end
```

In my index.js.erb

```
$('#job-id-container').append("<%= @job.message %>")
```

In my browser console I am getting response 304 and its not updating data on my page.

Please tell where I am wrong and suggest right code.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking.  Perhaps describe the error message, and what you are trying to accomplish.  In the meantime you could watch this and see if it answers your question: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I have

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

which was excepting data in json and i want to render script.
removing that line fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Personally not tested, try smth like this:

```
<script>
function repeat_ajax_call(){
   $.get("/job_statuses", function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#job-id-container').append(data.message);
   }, 'json');
}

$(repeat_ajax_call);
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", repeat_ajax_call);
</script>
```

**controller:**

```
def index       
  @job = JobStatus.last
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @job }
    format.json { render json: json_format(@job) }
    #OR
    format.json { render json: {data: @job}}
  end
end
```